# Is it possible to have two parameters with CommandParameter and RelayCommand in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, relaycommand

I want to do this:

XAML

```
<Button Content="Remove item" Command="{Binding ElementName=lvBackpacks, Path=DataContext.RemoveItemFromBackpackCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding property1} {Binding property2}}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
RemoveItemFromBackpackCommand = new RelayCommand<Type1, Type2>(param1, param2 =>
        {
            DoSomething(param1, param2);
        });
```

PS: This is just pseudocode to visualize. Its is obviously not working.

Is there some way I can pass two commandparameters?

Comment: you can create a class with two properties in it

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the way to do it. But hoe am I supposed to do that in the xaml code?

Comment: Are the properties comes from another element? If so, you could directly pass the element as the parameter.

Comment: _"But hoe am I supposed to do that in the xaml code?"_ -- the same way you set multiple properties of any object in XAML. For example, you can set `Window.DataContext`, `Window.Resources`, `Window.Content`, etc., with each of these properties receiving their own objects. Just do the same for your own composite object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you can't bind 2 separate objects to the same `CommandParameter` property.

**However**, you can create an object containing all the parameters that you need for your command and bind that instead.

Example:

Your `RemoveItem` command requires both a `Backpack` and a `SchoolGear`.

Create an object like the following,

```cs
public class SchoolGearItemViewModel
{
    Backpack Backpack { get; set; }
    SchoolGear SchoolGear { get; set; }
}
```

and change your command so that it takes a `SchoolGearItemViewModel` parameter instead of the other 2 objects.